# Non downloadable images using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I administrate a portfolio website, and I have to make the images non downloadable. I tried using the following script but it didn't work. I have installed jquery, but still, the same problem. Did I make a mistake in my code?

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").on("contextmenu",function(e){
         alert("Imaginile nu pot fi descarcate!");
       return false;
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you can't prevent a user from downloading your images/ copying your text

Comment: Add a transparent div overlay over the image

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$("img").on("contextmenu",function(e){
    alert("Imaginile nu pot fi descarcate!");
    return false;
});
```

**Example:**

```js
  $("img").on("contextmenu",function(e){
    alert("Imaginile nu pot fi descarcate!");
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://beta.phpformatter.com/themes/formatter/global/images/logo_formatter.png"/>
```

Comment: can't you see the jquery version?

Comment: what's problem in jquery version?

Comment: read the documentation on bind http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: See above example `3.2.1` version bind is working fine

Comment: Versiunea este jquery-3.2.1 . Daca nu merge asa, nu se poate cumva sa blochezi functia de a da click dreapta? Un exemplu poate fi vazut pe site-urile facute in portfoliobox ( [link](https://www.frostblog.portfoliobox.net) )

Comment: I drag and drop the image to new tab. Downloaded !!!

Comment: @ChandraKumar if you look in the source code of jquery `r.fn.extend({bind:function(a,b,c){return this.on(a,null,b,c)}`  `bind` basically is the `on` function

Comment: So, I uploaded Chandra's version of the script, still, sam thing. Nothing happens. Here's the link where I want it to work  [link](http://dastedo.ro/portfolio/index.html#)

Comment: @Stefan Doncean you are calling jquery `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` multiple times remove all only use ` <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
` and other `contextmenu` menu code add below jquery not above..

Comment: @ChandraKumar I updated it, I am only calling it from the googleapis.com

Comment: Check your updated code is here: http://jsbin.com/miqaremiga/edit?html

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you all! It works now

Comment: If helpful up vote this answer..